# C++ boost::split first of

Tags: c++, boost, split

I have a function for splitting string:

```
boost::split(r,lines[i], boost::is_any_of("="));
```

Above code splits string by every "=" I want to transform this code to split by only one "=".
Example:

```
__ga=223478=90234=234
```

After split:

```
__ga
223478=90234=234
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Boost is not necessary for this. A possible solution would be to use [`std::string::find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) and create two strings using [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) with the result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name_value = "__ga=223478=90234=234";
    std::string name;
    std::string value;

    const auto equals_idx = name_value.find_first_of('=');
    if (std::string::npos != equals_idx)
    {
        name = name_value.substr(0, equals_idx);
        value = name_value.substr(equals_idx + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        name = name_value;
    }

    std::cout << name << std::endl
              << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
__ga
223478=90234=234
```